# Iptables DNAT working in my own network, but not through VPN

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, nat, dnat

For some reasons I need to switch a server ip to another ip, in order to be seen by another computer elsewhere through vpn.
So I'm using iptables (didn't know any of that until yesterday) and testing with some result in my own network as follows:

- **serverA** = 172.19.128.239
- **ubuntu** = 172.19.128.237
- **clientB** = 172.19.128.248

**clientB** can request directly to **serverA** a service, and **serverA** provides it.

then I want that **clientB** requests the service to **ubuntu**, then ubuntu asks for it to **serverA**; **serverA** will answer to **ubuntu** and **ubuntu** will answer to **clientB**, which receives the service without ever knowing **serverA**

it's working using the following instructions:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 28000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.128.239:28000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 172.19.128.237
```

Please note that in order it to work, I need to reset the source address to the ubuntu, so that clientB receives it as if would be the same IP he specified. I don't know for what reason it would work also if I set instead of SNAT instructions, a MASQUERADE one:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

So this test is success, but, I need to make the same thing using another IP in another network connected through VPN (ipsec), namely **serverA2** 192.168.200.202

so I try to substitute to the above the ip as follows:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 28000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.202:28000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 172.19.128.237
```

But it doesn't work.
Notice that the VPN is working flawlessly as I can ping **serverA2** 192.168.200.202 both from **clientB** and from **ubuntu**. Also, it works even if I connect directly **clientB** to **serverA2** without passing from **ubuntu**.

For me now is obscure, what should I check?

Comment: Can you provide your routing table for all 3 systems?

Comment: I can for clientB (windows) and ubuntu, what command have i to input?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: 
I put the following commands, I missed one.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 172.19.128.248 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.202
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.200.202 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.128.248
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 172.19.128.237
```